# Is it possible to have a condition for a custom variable?

Tags: tfs

Suppose I want to create 3 custom release variables on TFS.

```
variable1
variable2
variable3
```

can i specify somewhere that to enter a variable3, user must enter variable1 and 2?

i cant prepopulate them myself because the input is quiet dynamic.

for now i am using an ugly method like this:

> variable2_MUST_ENTER_VARIABLE1_FIRST
>   variable3_MUST_ENTER_VARIABLE1_AND_VARIABLE2_FIRST

i wish there is a way to specify some sort of note next to the textbox or something :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a condition for a custom variable?

The short answer is yes. But I could not quite confirm if it is what you want.

To set a condition for a custom variable, we could enable a custom condition on the task in the pipeline:

[image]

**[Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#enable-a-custom-condition)**:

> Conditions are written as expressions. The agent evaluates the
>   expression beginning with the innermost function and works its way
>   out. The final result is a boolean value that determines if the task,
>   job, or stage should run or not. See the expressions topic for a full
>   guide to the syntax.

example:

```
and(succeeded(), ne(variables['variable1'], ''))
```

But, this condition for a custom variable will be applied at **build/release** time instead of entering the value of variable.

> i wish there is a way to specify some sort of note next to the textbox
>   or something

If you want to set the condition for a custom variable on the **UI**, I am afraid there is no such better way than you are using at this moment. You can add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Leo! I'll check it out :)